# Multiple Dynamic Column Select Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees, system.linq.dynamic

**Need:** To allow the user to select 3 columns to return from a local database.  With the help of another post I was able to return 1 column for a different application in the program, and I figured I could apply the same process here, but I'm not seeing how to allow the user to select multiple columns within the same query.  I see where `Func<>` accepts up to 17 overloads where all but one can be fields, but that doesn't seem to be the right approach.

**Example:**

TableX has the following columns:
A,B,C,D,E,F

```
A B C D E F
1 2 6 2 4 6
3 6 2 7 2 1
4 8 0 3 7 6
```

User Selects columns A, D, F

Query should return:

```
1 2 6
3 7 1
4 3 6
```

SQL statement to achieve this would be the following:

```
col1 = user selection 1.SelectedItem.ToString();
col2 = user selection 2.SelectedItem.ToString();
col3 = user selection 3.SelectedItem.ToString();


SELECT @col1, @ col2, @col3 FROM TableX;
```

Linq statement would be something like the following if I knew the fields that were going to be selected before runtime:

```
(from UserPageTbl in conn.Table<TableX>()
                         select new
                         {
                             TableX.A,
                             TableX.B,
                             TableX.C,
                         }

                       ).ToList();
```

*but I don't see how to parameterize selections in `LINQ` and pass them as a field in a select statement.

I get the concept of stacking sections of the Linq Expressions using an Expression Tree to return 1 column (like an `ORDERBY` and a `WHERE` clause), but I don't see how to do that for multiple columns.  It would work the same way to build a SQL statement.  I tried to use the `Expression.New` thinking that I needed the `new {}` to generate a list of the return columns and that didn't seem to be the right process.

**Current Set Up:** Using an extension method with an expression tree and lambda expression with `LINQ` to return 1 column.  This does work.  See Code below:

```
private static IQueryable<TResult> SelectByFieldName<T, TResult>(IQueryable<T> query, string fieldName)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    Expression body = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, fieldName);
    if (body.Type != typeof(TResult))
        body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(TResult));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(body, param);
    return query.Select(lambda);

}
```

**Problem:** I cannot figure out how to add additional columns to the lambda expression to return multiple selected columns.

**Trying to combine the items in a Select Query lambda expression as above:**

```
    private static IQueryable<TResult> GraphFields<T, a, b, c, TResult>(IQueryable<T> query, string aField, string bField, string cField)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        Expression aFieldBody = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, aField);
        if (aFieldBody.Type != typeof(TResult))
            aFieldBody = Expression.Convert(aFieldBody, typeof(TResult));
        Expression bFieldBody = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, bField);
        if (bFieldBody.Type != typeof(TResult))
            bFieldBody = Expression.Convert(bFieldBody, typeof(TResult));
        Expression cFieldBody = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, cField);
        if (cFieldBody.Type != typeof(TResult))
            cFieldBody = Expression.Convert(cFieldBody, typeof(TResult));
        
        var lambdaA = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(aFieldBody, param);
        var lambdaB = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(bFieldBody, param);
        var lambdaC = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(cFieldBody, param);

        return query.Select(lambdaA, lambdaB, lambdaC);


    }
```

I've also tried writing the following using the field variables in the "Select" statement,

```
return query.Select(new { aFieldBody, bFieldBody, cFieldBody }, param);
```

I've tried the following, because I thought multiple overloads would allow me to

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,a,b, TResult>>(aFieldBody, bFieldBody, cFieldBody, param);
```

I've also researched adding it to the PropertyOrField but it only accepts two overloads one for the parameter expression and 1 for the field name.  I just can't figure out how to append more columns.

Tried using Linq.Dynamic.Core, by doing the following:

```
var list = conn.Table<Table1>()
        .Where(t => t.User_ID == user).Distinct().ToList();

var listquery = list.AsQueryable();
        var Values = listquery
                .Select("new {Field1}")
                .ToDynamicList();
```

I get the following exception:
System.TypeInitializationException thrown
The type initializer for
System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.EnumerationsFromMscorlib threw an exception.

Comment: You are doing something without understanding how to use that later. Better to add use-cases. Maybe I can suggest solution. Basic problem here, you need class for every such projections.

Comment: LINQ is designed around static compile time types. Anonymous types are not created at runtime, and while it is possible to do so, they can be difficult to do much with. An easy approach to creating runtime anonymous types and queries is to use [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) and string queries.

Comment: @NetMage I tried using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core as suggested.  I've added this to the things I've tried above.  I'm not sure I'm setting the 'IQueryable<T>' up properly, because I'm getting a 'TypeInitalizationException' error for 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.EnumerationsFromMScorlib'.

Comment: Why are you using `ToList` to initialize `list`? Just set `listquery` to the expression without `ToList` and then do the `Select` on `listquery`.

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant, but it sounds like an error with the Dynamic LINQ library.